# A lot of queries to the eventmachine

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I use eventmachine to create a lot http queries.
Http server can perform these connections.
But periodically invoked 5-7 errback on 100 queries.
Why is it can be?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'
urls = []
100.times do 
  urls << 'http://127.0.0.1/'
end
if urls.size < 1
  puts "Usage: #{$0} <url> <url> <...>"
  exit
end

pending = urls.size

EM.run do
  urls.each do |url|
    http = EM::HttpRequest.new(url).get
    http.callback do
     puts "#{url}\n#{http.response_header.status} - #{http.response.length} bytes\n"
     pending -= 1
     EM.stop if pending < 1
    end
    http.errback do
      puts "E::#{url}\n" + http.error.to_s
      pending -= 1
      EM.stop if pending < 1
    end
  end
end
}
```

Comment: What kind of errors? This is probably to do with the other side of the connection, for example if the other server can only process 50 concurrent connections it might start refusing connections once that is exceeded

Comment: Just as a FYI, you might want to look into [Typhoeus and its associated Hydra](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) if you want to do multiple HTTP requests asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

How many queries can your localhost handle? You're sending 100 concurrent requests at 127.0.0.1, can it handle 100 concurrent requests? Otherwise, the requests will queue and are, possibly, timing out in EM::HttpRequest.

The EM::HttpRequest default connection timeout is 5 seconds and the default inactivity timeout is 10 seconds.

Try running ab against your localhost and see how many requests it can handle a second.